# delete 'b' of result for the function bin (x)

Tags: python, binary

How to properly remove the 'b' being in the result of the function bin (x)

Example:

```
bin(ord("\'"))
  -> '0b100111'
```

But I want this result

```
  -> '0100111'
```

Thank by advance,

Comment: What language? Python, I'd guess? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: try `bin(ord("\'"))[2:]`

Comment: python, sorry, i will modified, but i can't, thank for your response

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove just 'b' then replace can do the work

```
bin(ord("\'")).replace('b','')
```

But probably you also would like to remove leading '0' because it is also unnecessary and this could be done even simpler

```
bin(ord("\'"))[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of kev's answer (in the above comments ) but still another approch could be

```
bin(ord("\'")).split('b')[1]
```